# How to hide an Anchor tag's href link in the HTML?

Tags: html, web-scraping, anchor

Trying to prevent web scrapers/crawlers from grabbing this URL that's located in an anchor tag. I don't want to hide the icon from the page itself, just from the HTML.

```html
<a class="link" href="/hide_this_link_from_html"><img src="printIcon.jpg"/></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript.

```js
document.querySelector("a").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  var myURLOrPath = "/hide_this_link_from_html"
  event.preventDefault();
  alert("now use window.location.href to trigger navigate to " + myURLOrPath);
});
```

```html
<a class="link" href="#"><img width=124px src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.png"/></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to prevent search engines from scanning your pages should be creating a robot.txt file on your site. see https://www.robotstxt.org/ for usage).

**-> But, be careful some robots do not pay attention to this file.**..

A solution is to replace anchor target url when the user click on it...

**-> But scrapers are easily able to simulate a user click() event on a link...**

It exists some solutions / tips to avoid web scrappers... One of them is the use of CAPTCHA.

Comment: If a robot wants to scan your page, it isn't going to pay any attention to that at all.